# No changes are discovered after amend

Tags: jenkins

No commits are visible under pipeline run, thus affectedFiles list is empty, when using "git commit --amend" and "git push --force"

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM',
  branches: scm.branches,
  extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'LocalBranch'], [$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
  userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
])
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Why do you expect changes to b committed? did you add them (git add -A)

Comment: I have a custom method that operates with affectedFiles. Yes, I have updated files.